# O período entre duas datas

Tags: data, golang

Como obter um período entre duas datas?

```golang
d1, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-10-27T00:00:00Z")
d2, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2018-10-28T00:00:00Z")
// Não funciona.
fmt.Println(d2 - d1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar o método [`Sub`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Sub):

```golang
fmt.Println(d2.Sub(d1))
// 24h0m0s
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TEk9bDU0Wz8.